# KVM virtualization and thin clients

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, thin-client

Would this be a viable option for clients with 1-2 servers and around 20-40 end users, some of which work remotely.

Particularity I have been looking at red hat with KVM, but any distro will do.

Are there any guides out there for setting up and configuring KVM for thin clients?

Answer (score 1):

generally speaking, there is no reason why any station (thin or otherwise) shouldn't be able to connect to a VM running on a KVM hypervisor. Having said that, what do you have on those thin clients? windowsCE? some form of Linux?

Comment: It would basically be the users winxp/7 desktop

Comment: hmm, have you considered using RHEV? It's already there, with SPICE built in as the remote protocol, and if your setup is large, it definitely sounds like the perfect fit